# Can not place a sprite programmatically at the bottom left corner

Tags: coordinates, unity-game-engine

I have just started playing with unity. Yet, I haven't gotten my mind around the coordinate system. I have read various questions/answer, documents, watched tutorials. When I read docs, world, viewport and screen coordiantes make sense. However when I try to use those, results are completely surprising for me. That makes me think that I am missing something fundamentally important. Would someone help me please ?

Here is what I am trying to do. I am trying to build a game, which will have X number of pieces on a board of size MxN. I would like to place pieces PROGRAMMATICALLY. So, I expect to see a piece on the bottom left corner, when I place a piece on (0,0) screen coordinates. But to my surprise, piece gets placed approximately at the center of the board. I could not figure out why.

Here is my code:

```
 Vector3 BottomLeft = new Vector3 (0, 0, 0);
 GameObject token = Prefabs[0];
 GameObject go = Instantiate (token, BottomLeft , Quaternion.identity);
 SpriteRenderer renderer = go.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ();
 renderer.sortingLayerName = "Foreground";
 renderer.sortingOrder = 0;
```

And below is output of the code above:

[image]

As one can see that piece is placed at the center. I am well aware that I didn't "normalize" the coordinates. Below version of the code converts Screen points to world coordinates:

```
 Vector3 BottomLeft = new Vector3 (0, 0, 0);
 GameObject token = Prefabs[0];
 GameObject go = Instantiate (token, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint( BottomLeft ), Quaternion.identity);
 SpriteRenderer renderer = go.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ();
 renderer.sortingLayerName = "Foreground";
 renderer.sortingOrder = 0;
```

But the result is still somewhat similar to the first one, although piece is placed slightly to the left and down.

[image]

I was expecting the piece to be placed that bottom left corner but it is not. What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Below is the default settings for the cam I am using:

[image]

I also tried to set it in the code, in start method as follows: (please not that I tried either lines and the result is still the same:[ )

```
//      defaultCamera.transform.position = defaultCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint( new Vector3 (Screen.width / 2f, Screen.height / 2f, 0f));
//      defaultCamera.transform.position = defaultCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint( new Vector3 (-Screen.width / 2f, -Screen.height / 2f, 0f));
        //defaultCamera.transform.position = new Vector3 (-Screen.width / 2f, -Screen.height / 2f, -10f);
        defaultCamera.transform.position = new Vector3 (0f, 0f, -10f);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your tile is positioned correctly but the camera is not.

By default the camera is positioned so that the center of the coordinate system is at the center of the screen. Try to reposition the camera (either programtically in the Start Method or just via the unity GUI)

Hope this helped somehow. :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Apfelbox. I tried what you suggested but still no luck. Camera is located at (0,0,-10). My game view is set to 1080x1920. If this is the case, what's the bottom left coordinates ? (0,0)? or (-screen.width/2, -screen.height/2)?

Comment: I'm currently not at my own computer (where unity is installed). When I am home in a couple of hours and your issue is still not resolved, I'll have another look at the issue - in the meantime good luck

Comment: Thanks much.. I appreciate it :)